# How should I beat Empress of Light in Terraria?

Tags: terraria

I am having so much trouble with Empress of light. How should I go about beating her? I can't beat Moon Lord,so his gear is out of question, I have pillar weapons, beetle armor, a Celestial Shell, Mothron wings, and a comic car key. My friend has the same stuff as me, with Vampire Knifes. How can I improve my build?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you get battle armour that means that you have beat Golem, I recommend that you rush Pillar to get more powerful items

I'm ranger class player, the most simple way is using [rail](https://terraria.fandom.com/wiki/Minecart_Track) on the sky , (on the [Minecarts](https://terraria.fandom.com/wiki/Minecarts#Minecart) the most of projectile cant catch u when u at max speed )
get a [Vortex Beater](https://terraria.fandom.com/wiki/Vortex_Beater) ,[Chlorophyte Bullet](https://terraria.fandom.com/wiki/Chlorophyte_Bullet)
If you didn't have [Vortex Beater](https://terraria.fandom.com/wiki/Vortex_Beater) , you can use [mega shark](https://terraria.fandom.com/wiki/Megashark)

Also, reforge your items to +4% dmg will speed up

If you're a warrior player, you need an [arena](https://terraria.fandom.com/wiki/Guide:Arena) and repeat few timesé
for learning the boss skill for easier dodge it

Comment: Thank you, I did pillars, (though i had forgotten to add that to my post) I will try your method.Thanks!

Comment: Also, would you recommend regular Minecart or the one from Expert mechs?

Comment: @Yharon both work , but recommande Expert mechs one :)

Comment: thanks! I will let you know if this works!